# puppet 2.6.4 .deb package

Tags: puppet, packages, deb

Is there any 3rd party repositories that keeps up to date puppet client versions? I am looking for a puppet 2.6.4 .deb package?

Comment: for which distro/release?

Answer (score 2):

If by "third party" you mean "not the puppet developers", [Launchpad has one for Natty Narwhal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/puppet); the "Published versions" sections has links for e.g. [puppet 2.6.4-2ubuntu1 in i386](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/puppet/2.6.4-2ubuntu1), [puppet 2.6.4-2ubuntu1 in amd64](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/amd64/puppet/2.6.4-2ubuntu1).

Answer (score 2):

Official up to date version can be found from Debian Wheezy (testing) repository at http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/puppet.

You don't mention the distribution you use, but here's instructions for Debian Squeeze.

**How to use up to date version of Puppet in Debian Squeeze (stable)?**

Create a file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20release with content:

```
APT::Default-Release "stable";
```

Create a file /etc/apt/preferences.d/20puppet with content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 1

Package: puppet
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: puppet-common
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: puppetmaster
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: puppetmaster-common
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Create a file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/20testing.list with content:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main
```

Run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: mixing packages from testing into a stable release is a bad idea.  especially is security is a concern

Answer (score 1):

Debian backports has puppet 2.6.4 in their repository now.

http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/puppet